# Why does this give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm stunned, why does this code give me a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT 1500000

typedef struct {
    int p;
    int a;
    int b;
} triplet;

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    int i;
    triplet triplets[LIMIT];

    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
        triplets[i].p = 9; // remove this line and everything works fine
    }

    printf("%d\n", triplets[15].p);

    return 0; 
}
```

**EDIT**: After changing LIMIT to 150 I no longer get a segmentation fault, it prints random numbers instead.

**EDIT2**: Now I know what the site name stands for :) I made the array global and everything works fine now.

Comment: The numbers are whatever happened to be on your stack (since you're only initializing the first five array elements, but you're printing the 16th).

Comment: `it prints random numbers instead.` What are you actually printing ? Show the entire code.

Comment: @Mahesh: Please read the last three lines.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `EDIT2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack overflow!  Allocating 1500000 records at 12 bytes per record (assuming 4-byte `int`), requires more than 17 MB of stack space.  Make your `triplets` array global or dynamically allocate it.

As to your edit - shrinking the array will probably stop the stack overflow, but your `printf()` call will still print uninitialized data - `triplets[15].p` could be *anything* at the time you print it out.

Comment: I'm not too good with C, how would I change the code to avoid this?

Comment: Not to mention that you're trying to access uninitialized memory.  Make sure you assign `triplets[15].p` to something before you try reading it.

Comment: The line that was causing me the trouble was the line where I was going to initialize everything. But I got presented with a nice segmentation fault. The < 5 in the for loop was a random test of mine.

Comment: @nightcracker, most of the time the stack grows 'downward' in memory - that is, from high addresses to low ones.  So when you allocate 17 MB on the stack, like your program does, the base of the array is past the end of the stack and writing to the lower entries in the array causes the crash.  If you started initializing from the other end of the array (reverse the loop order), you'd probably not see the error until much later in the initialization process.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for whenever these problems happen again :)

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
triplet triplets[LIMIT];
```

you're allocating that on the stack.  Which is apparently too big for your system.

If you do

```
triplet* triplets=(triplet*)malloc(LIMIT*sizeof(triplet));
```

you'll allocate it on the heap and everything should be fine.  Be sure to free the memory when you're done with it

```
free(triplets);
```

Comment: Note that the OP could also preserve scope and allocate in the data segment instead of stack by changing the array declaration to `static triplet triplets[LIMIT];` which is likely a better option than making it a public global. The `malloc()` solution is probably the better approach in the long run, however.

Comment: Also, there isn't any need to cast the malloc return type in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc